# AutoHotKey For Loop

Tags: for-loop, autohotkey

I am trying to get a script like this in AHK but I don't know how to write it in AHK:

```
string arrow

if (leftArrowKeyPressed) {
    arrow = "left"
}
if (rightArrowKeyPressed) {
    arrow = "right"
}

if (arrow = "left") {
    for (int number = 1000; number < 10000; number++) {
        simulateKeyPresses(number)
        simulateKeyPresses(mousebutton0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the manual, then. It's quite good. A bit dry, but good. (I'm not the downvoter, but I don't disagree: this question shows no research effort whatsoever.)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this. It uses the While command. Your code might look something like the following:

```
~left::
While GetKeyState("left", "P") {
    Send {NUMBER}
    Send {MOUSE_BUTTON}
}
```

Line 1: '~left::' tells the following lines of code to activate when the left button is pressed. The '~' tells the program to still allow the 'left' arrow key to work. If you wanted this code to run and simultaneously block the 'left' arrow from working, remove the '~'.

Line 2: 'While GetKeyState("left", "P")' is self-explanatory. It's a 'while' loop that runs as long as you are holding the 'left' arrow key.

Line 3 and line 4 are for your code to go. Note that 'NUMBER' can be replace by any number 0-9, and 'MOUSE_BUTTON' can be replaced by either the left mouse button (LButton) or the right mouse button (RButton).

I hoped this helped get you started. Also, as formentioned, the AHK Help manual is very informative. You can search 'AutoHotKey Help' on your computer for your off-line version, or visit [this link](http://ahkscript.org/docs/AutoHotkey.htm) for the online version. These manuals include documentation of just about anything you could ever hope for, as well as a useful example of code at the bottom of each page.